# Google Styleguide Java Format for VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Is there a good extension or proven methodology to automatically format Java code in VSCode to adhere to Google's Java Styleguide? Nothing from the list of links below seems to work for my set-up. I get a soft-fail and nothing changes about formatting.

```
Version: 1.39.2 (user setup)
Commit: 6ab598523be7a800d7f3eb4d92d7ab9a66069390
Date: 2019-10-15T15:35:18.241Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.16299
```

[google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format)
[GitHub - Formatting VSCode : 419](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/419)
[GitHub - Formatting VSCode : 450](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/450)
[GitHub - Formatting VSCode : 663](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/663)
[Formatter Settings](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Formatter-settings)
[Eclipse Java Google Style XML](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml)
[VS Java Editing - Main Page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-editing#_formatting)
[VSCode Extension - Checkstyle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shengchen.vscode-checkstyle)

Comment: after install [checkstyle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shengchen.vscode-checkstyle),you should configurate some settings

Comment: @Joe H did you get this working? I'm looking though more or less the same resources, and although I do have a `google-java-format` on `PATH` that can (correctly) format a file, I haven't been able to make the `Format Document` action actually invoke that correctly.

Comment: @TomasAschan not yet unfortunately. I have not been able to find a solid working example to follow, but I am suspecting that it has to do with conflicting formatting settings. Setting a format in Eclipse seems to be what pops up the most, but the steps recommended on github aren’t exactly clear to me / match with v2019.06

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent some time working on this same problem yesterday. The best and most reliable solution I was able to come up with was to install `google-java-format` into my path and then use the RunOnSave extension to invoke the binary for files with the `.java` extension.

Install emeraldwalk/vscode-runonsave:

```
$ code --install-extension emeraldwalk.RunOnSave
```

Install google-java-format for your system:

```
# Example using Homebrew on OS X
$ brew install google-java-format
```

Configure RunOnSave in Visual Studio Code settings:

```
{
  "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "match": "\\.java$",
        "cmd": "google-java-format --replace ${file}"
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

I describe more of the methodology in [this blog post](https://www.sethvargo.com/using-google-java-format-with-vs-code/).

Answer (score 2):

[google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) requires Java 16.0.1 SDK. You have to install it first.

There is an extension [ilkka.google-java-format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ilkka.google-java-format) on the Visual Studio Code marketplace, but it is incompatible with current version.

I have to change it this way:

1. Open file : `C:\Documents and Settings\<USERNAME>\.vscode\extensions\ilkka.google-java-format-1.0.2\out\extension.js`
2. Update function **provideDocumentRangeFormattingEdits** this way:

   ```
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let stdout = "";
       let stderr = "";
       let child = cp.spawn("java.exe",
           [
               "--add-exports", "jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED",
               "--add-exports", "jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED",
               "--add-exports", "jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED",
               "--add-exports", "jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED",
               "--add-exports", "jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
               "-jar",
               executablePath,
               "--lines",
               `${range.start.line}:${range.end.line}`,
               "-",
           ]);
   ```
3. In *Settings -> Preferences* set executablePath to path to jar archive (**google-java-format-1.10.0-all-deps.jar**)

Enjoy

Comment: This is a great solution for Windows-users, the xmls to refer to in the more official docs are over 5 years old and does not follow the more recent changes.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the `all-deps` JAR from the [releases page](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/releases) of the google/google-java-format repo and used the [External formatters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteefH.external-formatters) plugin with the following configuration:

```json
        "externalFormatters.languages": {
            "java": {
                "command": "java",
                "arguments": [
                    "-jar",
                    "<path>/google-java-format-1.15.0-all-deps.jar",
                    "-"
                ]
            }
        },
        "[java]": {
            "editor.formatOnSave": true,
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "SteefH.external-formatters"
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

To Config "`Google Java Style`" as the default format of Java Program on `VSCode`, please:

1.Install "`Extension Pack for Java`".

e.g: I revert "`Extension Pack for Java`" to "`Version v0.9.1`" for my "`Java 1.8`", and revert "`Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat`" to "`v0.64.1`" for "`Java1.8`".

You need to make sure that compiling, running and debugging are successful before enter "`Next Step`".

2.Set the default formatter of `Java` into "`RedHatJavaStyle`".

Using hotKeyMap to open the `Settings` of `VSCode`, e.g: `Cmd` + `,` in macOS, or just click the logo of `VSCode` "`Code`" button and choose "`Preference`" menu and then click "`Setting`",

Type "`javahome`" in the "`Search settings`" space, then click "`Edit in settings.json`", input the below code into your "`settings.json`", e.g: macOS's "`settings.json`" is under "`/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`".

```
"java.format.settings.url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml",
"java.format.settings.profile": "GoogleStyle",
"java.format.settings.imports.onDemand": false,
"java.format.settings.imports.regexp": "^[a-z.]*",
"[java]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java",
    "editor.tabSize": 2
}
```

Then restart the "`VSCode`", and then reopen, Using "`shift`" + "`alt/option`" + "`f`" to automatic the format style of Java Program into "`Google Java Style`".

END!

Answer (score 0):

try to configurate settings like:

```
"java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
"checkstyle.enable": true,
"checkstyle.configurationPath": "config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml",
"checkstyle.checkstylePath": "C:/dev/tools/checkstyle-8.8-all.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

to use google formatter in vsc, navigate to the

```
settings -> language and support -> formatting
```

then in the `Java>Format>Settings: URL` give the path of the google formatter xml file.

If you do not have the googleformatter.xml file, then use the attached file

https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can try new extension which cane be found here.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mmilic.java-google-format

It works without any hustle, there are no configurations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).